# AppCode 3.2 highlights objective-c syntax with errors but build succeed

Tags: ios, xcode7, appcode

I've updated AppCode to the latest 3.2 version. 
I open, build and run the project succesful but AppCode highlights the syntax with red underlines:

[image]

I use XCode 7 and I've noticed a message in AppCode:

> You are using Xcode 7.0 which is not yet supported. We recommend that
>   you switch to the latest stable Xcode 6.

But if build works fine I wouldn't downgrade XCode to older version just to get correct syntax highlighting (if downgrading would help at all).

Have I missed something?

Comment: You can download Xcode 6 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads and install it alongside your Xcode 7 (rename the folder and drop it in Applications). Next time you start AppCode it will detect Xcode6 and offer to use that.